# Some grammar for sites

Tags: articles, proper-nouns, capitalization

I'm describing a bar graph and I'm little bit confused.

I want to write something like that:

`On the second bar we can see the first peak: somesite.com was visited by almost 19 percent of internet users.`

Should there be any article before the name of the site? Should I write the name of the site with a capital letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the *article* is not required before the site's URL. Maybe, because it serves something like a proper noun. If you want to put it anyhow, you may say...

> The website somesite.com was visited....

In rare cases, some authors do put *the* before the site's name; for example- *The Smashing Magazine reports...* OR *The Wikipedia describes...* but then note that that's the site's name and not URL.